# export doesn't work

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

**test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
export test_var=1
```

Run the script, then continue to run the command in the terminal: `echo $test_var`, I got nothing. Why? Since `test_var` was exported, I thought I could continue to use the variable in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

export is to allow subshells to inherit the variable, it does nothing to allow a subshell to change a value in the parent.

Answer (score 1):

For it to change your current shell environment, run the script with either

```
. test.sh
```

or

```
source test.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. Though I have used the `source` command for thousands of times, I never thought about it seriously. I just tested it, the current shell will source the variables in the script whether the variable was exported or not. It's really helpful.